# SQL- I need script text file need to know which tables and views and stored procedures having that script

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having script text file that inside having

1. Create procedure
2. Create table
3. alter table
4. alter procedure
5. alter view
6. create view etc..

I need to know views, SPs, tables names and its roles (create or alter) when I run the script.

Example following are text file.

and the result should be following

`proc, alter, bal.vendor
table, select, manager 
table, create, employee 
table, alter, persons`

Comment: Hello, can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47362567/edit) your question and be specific, cause your question is not clear, what is the issue? what did you try to solve it?

Comment: I think u will get this information in message tab in management studio

Comment: edited. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sql query:

```
SELECT name, type, type_desc, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE modify_date > '01-01-2017' -- pass your date
```

- name: is the name of the sp, table or view that was modified or created
- type: indicates type of the object

The objects that were newly created will have the same date for both `create_date` and `modify_date`. Use this modified query to show if it was new or modified:

```
SELECT name, type, type_desc, 
case when  create_date = modify_date then 'Created' Else 'Altered' end
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE modify_date > '01-01-2017'
```

[image]

Comment: No i am not looking for this. edited the question check now

Comment: You have all the columns here, change the select query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

All those are called `Objects`, so the only thing may come up to your mind is to use `sys.all_objects` view which can be found in:

> YourDatabase -> Views -> SystemViews

All those objects has a `type`:

```
U  -> USER_TABLE
IF -> SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
P  ->  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
TR ->  SQL_TRIGGER
V  ->   VIEW
...etc
```

So, you can query this `View` to get the results you want as:

```
SELECT object_id,
       name,
       type, 
       type_desc, 
       CASE WHEN create_date = modify_date THEN 'Created' ELSE 'Altered' END AS state, 
       create_date, 
       modify_date
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'); --Optional you can remove it if you wan all types of objects
```